# Selected options in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have edit form and I need to get selected options from database to be selected by default when page loads.

## Logic

1. Get post data (done)
2. Get all tags (done)
3. Get post tags (done)
4. Select post tags from tags list by default (need help)

## Code

`HTML`

```
<vs-select
    :key="tags.length"
    filter
    :label="$t('posts.tags')"
    v-model="form.tags"
    multiple
    state="success"
>
    <vs-option
        v-for="tag in tags"
        :key="tag.id"
        :label="tag.name"
        :value="tag.id"
    >
        {{ tag.name }}
    </vs-option>
</vs-select>
```

`Script`

```
data() {
    return {
      tags: [], // all tags
      form: {
        tags: [], // post tags
      },
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchPost(); // get post data including it's tags
    this.fetchTags(); // get all tags
},
methods: {
    fetchPost() {
      axios
        .get("/api/admin/posts/" + this.$route.params.id, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            //....
            this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("error", error);
        });
    },
    fetchTags() {
      axios
        .get("/api/admin/tags", {
            headers: {
                    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
            },
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.tags = response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
    },
},
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: `this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags;` does not do the job?

Comment: no, I guess it might be referred to ids of those tags

Comment: could you output `this.form.tags` after `this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags;`?

Comment: this `response.data.data.tags;` is an array, under each row of it has `id` I need to set those ids to my `this.form.tags`

Comment: https://ibb.co/3ykNg0b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my fetching code to the following line and it's working now

```
this.form.tags = response.data.data.tags.map((x) => x.id);
```